# Passing unlimited arguments to logging function in C++17

Tags: c++, logging, arguments, c++17

So I have implemented a rather trivial logger but I would like to extend it so I can pass arguments of data to it, possibly with formatting and I can't seem to figure out how to best do it.

So far it is written like so:

```cpp
// Standard Headers.
#include <ostream>
#include <variant>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

namespace Logger {
    // Various logging severity levels.
    enum class Level {
        Info
    };

    class Log {
    public:
        // Takes standard streams cout, cerr, etc.
        explicit Log(std::ostream& p_stream) : m_log(&p_stream) {}

        // Create logger using std::make_unique<std::ofstream>(...) so ownership is passed.
        explicit Log(std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> p_stream) : m_log(std::move(p_stream)) {}

        template <typename T>
        inline void info(T&& p_message);

    private:
        template <typename T>
        void log(T&& p_msg) const {
            auto const t_lock = std::lock_guard(*m_lock);
            std::visit([&](auto&& p_ptr) {
                (*p_ptr) << p_msg;
            }, m_log);
        };

        std::ostream& stream() const {
            return std::visit([](auto&& ptr) -> std::ostream& {
                return *ptr;
            }, m_log);
        }

        template <typename T>
        inline void add(Logger::Level p_level, T&& p_message);

        std::variant<std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>, std::ostream*> m_log;
        std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> m_lock = std::make_unique<std::mutex>();
        std::array<std::string_view, 1> m_levels = { "Info" };
    };

    template <typename T>
    void Log::add(Level p_level, T&& p_message) {
        auto const f_lock = std::lock_guard(*m_lock);
        stream() << m_levels[static_cast<size_t>(p_level)] << ": " << p_message << '\n';
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline void Log::info(T&& p_message) {
        add(Level::Info, p_message);
    }
}

int main() {
    auto logger = Logger::Log(std::cout);
    logger.info("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

What I would like to do is when I use `.info()` be able to specify any number of arguments which will be replaced when writing to the log, similar to this:

```
logger.info("Some error message with arg: {}", 1);
```

How would I go about doing this? What is the best approach?

Comment: My first thought was a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: Check out the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/README.rst).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). This is a non optimized version (uses copies instead of references, removes item from vector etc) but the basic idea is to convert a compile-time parameter pack to a run time one with this line:

```
 std::vector<std::any> a = {args ...};
```

You can use references with, say, `std::vector<std::any> a = {std::ref(args)...};`

The full function would be like that:

```
template<typename ... many>
void safe_printf2(const char *s, many ... args)
{
    using namespace std; 
    vector<any> a = {args ...};

    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%') {
            if (*(s + 1) == '%') {
                ++s;
            }
            else {

                if (a.empty())
                    throw logic_error("Fewer arguments provided to printf");

                if (a[0].type() == typeid(string)) cout << any_cast<string>(a[0]);
                if (a[0].type() == typeid(int)) cout << any_cast<int>(a[0]);
                if (a[0].type() == typeid(double)) cout << any_cast<double>(a[0]);

                a.erase(a.begin());
                s++;
            }
        }
        cout << *s++;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
 safe_printf2("Hello % how are you today? I have % eggs and your height is %","Jack"s, 32,5.7);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reasons, I do something similar this way (you will have to adapt it to your needs):

```
inline
std::ostream &
txt(std::ostream &output,
    const char *format)
{
  return output << format;
}

template<typename First,
         typename ...Args>
inline
std::ostream &
txt(std::ostream &output,
    const char *format,
    First &&first,
    Args &&...args)
{
  while(*format)
  {
    if(*format=='%')
    {
      return txt(output << std::forward<First>(first),
                 ++format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    output << *format++;
  }
  return output;
}
```

The two previous functions use the marker `%` in a format string to inject the next argument (**whatever** it is, a value, a format specifier, a custom object...) in the stream.

Of course some adapters could ease the usage:

```
template<typename ...Args>
inline
std::string
txt(const char *format,
    Args &&...args)
{
  std::ostringstream output;
  txt(output, format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return output.str();
}
```

For example:

```
std::ostream &
operator<<(std::ostream &output,
           const MyStuff &ms)
{
  return output << '[' << ms.member1 << '|' << ms.member2 << ']'; 
}
...
MyStuff my_stuff= ... ;
auto msg=txt("an integer %, a (formatted) real %% and something else %\n",
             12, std::setprecision(12), 34.56, my_stuff);
```

Then it should be possible to adjust `Log::add()` (then `Log::info()` and anything related) to make it usable in a way similar to what was expected in the question

```
logger.info("Some error message with arg: %", 1);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is the difference between the `%` and the `%%`?

Comment: @Rietty there are two `%` because we inject the formatter (if needed, first `%`) then the value (second `%`). Each `%` can be substituted by anything. Even `'%'` ;^)